# Client sends many "Client Hello" messages for initiaing 1 request

Tags: ssl, sslhandshakeexception

Is it possible for a client to send multiple "Client Hello" requests for one request to the server in fraction of milliseconds ?

Eg. In my case, the client sends 2 "Client Hello" messages to the server consecutively, before the server responds with "Server Hello" .

Comment: So you have seen two CLIENT_HELLO messages in Wireshark? Are you sure you have seen two CLIENT_HELLO messages and not one CLIENT_HELLO fragmented to two IP packets?

Comment: Or it could have been that you saw 2 ClientHello before there were 2 TCP connection. Please provide the actual pcap so that one can find out what really happened.

Comment: In any case, as is, this is not about programming, so this is off topic here.